# percent is not working on the height

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have this div

```
<div style="overflow :auto ;height:480px" >
```

inside a table,

the content in the table is dynamically changing so the height of the div is not known.

It was working well, but now I want to use percent instead of 480px

I tried height:60% and height:30% but it doesn't work.

**by doesn't work I mean** that the tables goes down to the page. On other words, the div keep downing to the down.

why please?

Comment: "downing to the down"? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: "it doesn't work" What doesn't work?

Comment: @jsve please try to read the quediton, i make it bold

Comment: @jsve that means like there is no limit to the height

Comment: @Pattle I can't , i am using asp.net, but I can give you any other information you need

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli when using percents in css the percents are relative to the parent object. In the case of a table this would be the `td` or `tr` depending on how you have your table set up. These tags automatically resize to show **ALL** the content. If you want there to be a cut off that creates a scroll bar for the `DIV` you **HAVE** to define a definate height in px, em, pt, ect that isn't a relative size unit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

HTML

```
<div class="dynamic">
    your div content here
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dynamic {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* your other properties here */
}
```

Comment: that is not what i was asking about my friend, i was asking how to limit the height, not making it auto

Comment: to limit the height either set a percentage based height, or set a fixed size in px. But be careful, the proportions will be lost and it may not appear how you would like it to appear depending on your content.